# Free software to format an illustrated children fairy tale on Mac

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, free

I have the text and the drawings are scanned and saved.
I am looking for:

- A nice modern font
- Formatting software that enables me to design my book with writing and pictures
- Editing software to work on the drawings to make them really friendly

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to look at open source software.

- For fonts, take a look at the excellent selection at [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/)
- For editing the illustrations, you can take a look at [Krita](https://krita.org/) or [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/)
- For laying out the book, [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) might be a good bet.

Comment: You mean best bet is to look for free software, changes little for the end user whether it is open source or not. I would definitely recommend Krita (except for it's history of poor vector handling) which happens to be open source, but there are good freeware programs out there as well.